# Nested MigLayouts stretch out of bounds when restoring from fullscreen

Tags: swing, window-resize, miglayout

I have a [non-trivial Swing app running on Windows](https://github.com/trdesilva/autorecorder) that has an issue with window resizing: when I maximize the window and then restore it, the main panel doesn't resize properly with the window. The panel stays between the fullscreen size and the current size until I drag the window border around and force a few more resize attempts. I found that the minimal repro case is close to the following:

**JAVA**

```
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("TEST");
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
        outerPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, insets 0", "[grow]", "[grow]"));
        
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        innerPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, insets 10", "[75%:75%:100%]", "[grow]"));
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea("text 1");
        innerPanel.add(text, "cell 0 0, grow");
        
        outerPanel.add(innerPanel, "cell 0 0, grow");
        
        mainWindow.getContentPane().add(outerPanel);
    
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
```

If I put `ComponentListener`s on `text`, `innerPanel`, and `outerPanel` here and print out each component's width on resize, I can see that `outerPanel` resizes properly, but `innerPanel` and `text` both only shrink by an amount proportionate to how far they are from the correct size each update. This seems to be caused by the minimum-size column constraint on innerPanel being set to a value such that the minimum width when in fullscreen is larger than the maximum width of the window when not in fullscreen. When I run this code, I get a 120px-wide window that maximizes to 2560px; it doesn't repro if the minimum-size constraint is 1% (25.6px when maximized), but it does if the minimum-size is 5% (128px).

My question is, why? Why does the resize not initially work properly but eventually converge to the right value if I make enough incremental changes to the stretched dimension? And how can I get my minimum-size constraints to work when maximizing and restoring the window?

For the places in my actual program that are exhibiting the problem, there's a `RecordingListPanel` inside of a `JTabbedPane` inside of the `mainPanel` `JPanel` in `MainWindow` inside of the `metaPanel` `JPanel` in `MainWindow`. Here are the relevant excerpts:

**JAVA**

```
// RecordingListPanel
setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, insets 2", "[75%:75%:90%]2[10%::300]", "[][grow]"));

//tabbedPane
tabbedPane.add("Recordings", recordingListPanel);

// mainPanel
mainLayout = new CardLayout();
mainPanel.setLayout(mainLayout);
mainPanel.add(tabbedPane, "mainView");

// metaPanel
metaPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, insets 0 0 0 0", "[grow]", "[grow][30!]"));
metaPanel.add(mainPanel, "cell 0 0, grow");
mainFrame.getContentPane().add(metaPanel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the root cause, but I was able to work around the issue. I added a `ComponentListener` to the inner panel (`mainPanel`), which has a `componentResized()` method that checks if its current size is larger than the outer panel (`metaPanel`) and resizes again if it is.

```java
mainPanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
    {
        int width = mainPanel.getWidth();
        int height = mainPanel.getHeight();
        boolean shouldAdjust = false;
        if(mainPanel.getWidth() > metaPanel.getWidth())
        {
            width = metaPanel.getWidth();
            shouldAdjust = true;
        }
        if(mainPanel.getHeight() > metaPanel.getHeight())
        {
            height = metaPanel.getHeight() - 30;
            shouldAdjust = true;
        }

        if(shouldAdjust)
        {
            mainPanel.setSize(width, height);
            tabbedPane.setSize(width, height);
        }
    }
});
```